# Dúvida sobre extração de valores usando soup.findAll() em Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

Boa tarde a todos.

Estou estudando python e aprendendo a fazer extração de dados em sites e para dá início a esse aprendizado estou criando um programa que irá extrair os dados da lotofacil do site da caixa econômica e me retornar os valores sorteados em determinado concurso.
Pelos exemplos que vi na internet, é possível fazer a busca pela  e pelo  ou <parâmetro>, no entanto, verifiquei que a página, da caixa, que possui todos os resultados por concurso não possui um , ou seja, só possuem o  e  dentro de uma tabela .

Já consegui extrair os dados de toda a linha de determinado concurso, no entanto, não estou conseguindo tratar os dados da linha e pegar somente: número do concurso e números sorteados. O meu código ele está mostrando todo os valores da linha.

Alguém poderia me dá uma luz?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

req = requests.get( "http://loterias.caixa.gov.br/wps/portal/loterias/landing/lotofacil/!ut/p/a1/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfGjzOLNDH0MPAzcDbz8vTxNDRy9_Y2NQ13CDA0sTIEKIoEKnN0dPUzMfQwMDEwsjAw8XZw8XMwtfQ0MPM2I02-AAzgaENIfrh-FqsQ9wBmoxN_FydLAGAgNTKEK8DkRrACPGwpyQyMMMj0VAcySpRM!/dl5/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/pw/Z7_HGK818G0K85260Q5OIRSC42046/res/id=historicoHTML/c=cacheLevelPage/=/" )
soup = BeautifulSoup( req.content, "html.parser" )

todas_linhas = soup.findAll("tr")

## LOCALIZA EM TODAS AS LINHAS 'td' O texto '2208', GUARDA DA VARIÁVEL temp ##
# A CONDIÇÃO if VERFICA NA VARIÁRIL temp E SÓ RETORNA OS VALORES QUE SÃO DIFERENTES DE None #

for tr in todas_linhas:
    temp = tr.find('td', text='2208')
    if temp != None:
        print (tr.text)
```

Espero que tenham entendido a minha dúvida e obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Não seria `print(temp.text)`?

Comment: se eu printar essa variável temp.text.. ele só vai me retornar o valor: 2208

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara, essa deu trabalho hein. kkkkkk.

Seu código está no caminho correto, o problema está na página que em algumas linhas foi adicionado uma nova tabela, por exemplo, coluna cidade além de algumas sujeirinhas na transformação de tag html para texto.

Segue a solução abaixo, transformando o retorno num dataframe, será perfeito para analises, filtros e gráficos se desejar.

Mais abaixo, um código exibindo linha por linha, veja que ele zera a contagem e trás sujeira de uma linha para outra.

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

url = "http://loterias.caixa.gov.br/wps/portal/loterias/landing/lotofacil/!ut/p/a1/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfGjzOLNDH0MPAzcDbz8vTxNDRy9_Y2NQ13CDA0sTIEKIoEKnN0dPUzMfQwMDEwsjAw8XZw8XMwtfQ0MPM2I02-AAzgaENIfrh-FqsQ9wBmoxN_FydLAGAgNTKEK8DkRrACPGwpyQyMMMj0VAcySpRM!/dl5/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/pw/Z7_HGK818G0K85260Q5OIRSC42046/res/id=historicoHTML/c=cacheLevelPage/=/"
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser" )

todas_linhas = soup.findAll("tr")

lista = []
lista_aux = []
for x in todas_linhas:
    z = x.text
    i = 0
    linhas_validas = 'N'
    lista_aux = []

    #Transforma o texto em lista
    for xx in z.split('\n'):

        if i == 1 and xx != "":
            linhas_validas = 'S'

        if linhas_validas == 'S' and i >=1 and i<=17:
            lista_aux.append(xx)

        i += 1

    if linhas_validas == "S" and len(lista_aux) ==17:
        lista.append(lista_aux)

#Transformar lista em dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(lista)

#Pega primeira linha
headers = df.iloc[0]

#Transforma linha em cabeçalho
df.columns = [headers]

#Apaga a primeira linha porque virou cabeçalho
df = df.iloc[1:]

#imprime os 10 primeiros registros
print(df.head(5).to_string())

#Imprime todo o dataframe
#print(df.to_string())

#Imprime a quantidade de linhas e colunas
print()
print('Linhas e Colunas Total:')
print(df.shape)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

url = "http://loterias.caixa.gov.br/wps/portal/loterias/landing/lotofacil/!ut/p/a1/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfGjzOLNDH0MPAzcDbz8vTxNDRy9_Y2NQ13CDA0sTIEKIoEKnN0dPUzMfQwMDEwsjAw8XZw8XMwtfQ0MPM2I02-AAzgaENIfrh-FqsQ9wBmoxN_FydLAGAgNTKEK8DkRrACPGwpyQyMMMj0VAcySpRM!/dl5/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/pw/Z7_HGK818G0K85260Q5OIRSC42046/res/id=historicoHTML/c=cacheLevelPage/=/"
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser" )

todas_linhas = soup.findAll("tr")

for x in todas_linhas:
    z = x.text
    i = 0
    for xx in z.split('\n'):
        print(str(i)+" - "+str(xx))
        i += 1
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pesquisar o concurso

```
print()
print('Digite o Código do Concurso: ')
codigoConcurso = input()


df_desejado = df.iloc[[int(codigoConcurso)-1]]

print(df_desejado)

data = str(df_desejado.iloc[0][1])
bola1 = str(df_desejado.iloc[0][2])
bola2 = str(df_desejado.iloc[0][3])
#outras variaveis
bola15 = str(df_desejado.iloc[0][16])

print()
print('data: '+str(data))
print('bola 1: '+str(bola1))
print('bola 3: '+str(bola2))
print('bola 15: '+str(bola15))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Valeu Gilmar,
Eu estava tendo problemas para adicionar os resultado em listas, pois os '\n' estava indo junto e isso estava me aborrecendo..
Vou dá uma estudada no código para ver o que eu faço...
Obrigado!

Comment: Agora tenho que ver como faço pra entrar com o valor do concurso ele ele me mostrar somente as bolas sorteadas.

Comment: De nada.

Tá na mão, coloquei no final da postagem como consultar um concurso, só atualizar essa página que vc já deve vê

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado por ajudar Gilmar Vaz. Agora vou estudar Interface gráfica para integrar ao código.

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

url ="http://loterias.caixa.gov.br/wps/portal/loterias/landing/lotofacil/!ut/p/a1/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfGjzOLNDH0MPAzcDbz8vTxNDRy9_Y2NQ13CDA0sTIEKIoEKnN0dPUzMfQwMDEwsjAw8XZw8XMwtfQ0MPM2I02-AAzgaENIfrh-FqsQ9wBmoxN_FydLAGAgNTKEK8DkRrACPGwpyQyMMMj0VAcySpRM!/dl5/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/pw/Z7_HGK818G0K85260Q5OIRSC42046/res/id=historicoHTML/c=cacheLevelPage/=/"
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser" )

todas_linhas = soup.findAll("tr")

lista = []
lista_aux = []
resultado = []
for x in todas_linhas:
    z = x.text
    i = 0
    linhas_validas = 'N'
    lista_aux = []

    #Transforma o texto em lista
    for xx in z.split('\n'):

        if i == 1 and xx != "":
            linhas_validas = 'S'

        if linhas_validas == 'S' and i >=1 and i<=17:
            lista_aux.append(xx)

        i += 1

    if linhas_validas == "S" and len(lista_aux) ==17:
        lista.append(lista_aux)

#Transformar lista em dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(lista)

#Pega primeira linha
headers = df.iloc[0]

#Transforma linha em cabeçalho
df.columns = [headers]

#Apaga a primeira linha porque virou cabeçalho
df = df.iloc[1:]

#imprime, por default, os 5 primeiros registros
#print(df.head().to_string())

#imprime, por default, os 5 últimos registros
print (df.tail().to_string())

#Imprime todo o dataframe
#print(df.to_string())

#Imprime a quantidade de linhas e colunas
print()
print('Linhas e Colunas Total:')
print(df.shape)

print()
print('Digite o Código do Concurso: ')
codigoConcurso = input()

df_desejado = df.iloc[[int(codigoConcurso)-1]]

print(df_desejado)

data = str(df_desejado.iloc[0][1])

print ('-')
resultadoString = (df_desejado.iloc[0][2:17].tolist())
# converter os valores String para int dentro da lista (resultado)
resultadoFinal = []
for i in resultadoString:
    resultadoFinal.append(int(i))
#print (resultadoFinal)
        
print()
print('data: '+str(data))

## Jogos feitos pelo usuário.
jogos = ([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,12,13,15,17,20,21,22,23], [5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,16,17,19,20,22,23,24])
        
#---variáveis globoais-----#
contador = 0
pontos = 0

## Laço para conferir os 8 jogos feitos.
while (contador <= len(jogos)):
    for i in jogos[contador]:
        for j in resultadoFinal:
            if i == j:
                pontos += 1
    #totais.append(pontos)
    
    print("O jogo ", jogos[contador], " conseguiu ", pontos, " pontos!")
    pontos = 0
contador += 1
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]